# How to pass data from Controller to view in J2ee with spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a simple J2ee application with spring mvc. Now I want to call a method from the jsp page to his controller and I want to have an information from the controller. So I have write this code:

registrazione.jsp:

```
<script language="javascript">  

    function saveRigaTable2(){

        try{
            var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
            var ajaxHandler = new AjaxHandler('POST', '<c:url value="${pageName}"/>.html', false);   
            ajaxHandler.encodeParameter('method', 'saveItems');
            ajaxHandler.encodeParameter('nome', nome);

            ajaxHandler.callbackHandler = function()
            {           
                if (ajaxHandler.getRequest().readyState == 4)
                {   
                    if (ajaxHandler.getRequest().status == 200)
                    {
                        var xmlDoc = ajaxHandler.getRequest().responseXML;

                        var itemsException = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("exception");
                        alert(itemsException.length);
                        var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("registrazioneOK");
                        alert(items.length);
                        if (itemsException.length!=0)
                        {
                            var punto=itemsException[0];
                            alert(punto.getAttribute("text"));
                            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML=punto.getAttribute("text");
                            alert('Impossibile1 eseguire l\' operazione');
                        }
                        if (items.length!=0)
                        {
                            var punto=items[0];
                            alert(punto.getAttribute("text"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            ajaxHandler.startRequest();   
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert('Impossibile eseguire l\' operazione');
        }      
    }
</script>
```

This is the method of Controller:

```
public ModelAndView saveItems(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
        List dataSet = new ArrayList();
        Map dataItem = new HashMap();
        List attributes = new ArrayList();   
        Map model=new HashMap();
        try
        {
            String nome=request.getParameter("nome");
            User user = new User();
            user.setNome(nome);
            if(modelManager.getUserManager().saveUser(user)){
                //request.getSession().setAttribute("rilasciataModificataConf", "SI");
                //registrazione avvenuta con successo
                dataItem.put("tagName", "registrazioneOK");
                attributes.add(new Entity("text", "Complimenti. Registrazione avvenuta con successo." ));
                dataItem.put("attributes", attributes);
                dataSet.add(dataItem);  
                model.put("dataSet", dataSet);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            dataItem.put("tagName", "exception");
            attributes.add(new Entity("text", "Error in saving the current row" ));
            dataItem.put("attributes", attributes);
            dataSet.add(dataItem);  
            model.put("dataSet", dataSet);
            LoggerFactory.logStackTrace(e);
        }
        request.setAttribute("model", model);
        return new ModelAndView("secure/ajax_callback", model);
    }
```

This is the ajax_callback.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<dataSet>
   <c:forEach var="dataItem" items="${dataSet}">
        <<c:out value="${dataItem.tagName}"/> 
        <c:forEach var="attribute" items="${dataItem.attributes}">
            <c:out value="${attribute.id}"/>="<c:out value='${attribute.description}'/>" 
        </c:forEach>/>
    </c:forEach>
</dataSet>
```

When I run this code, I can't read the information, the lenght of the items is all time 0.
Where is my error?

EDIT: this is the reposnse of xml that I have from ajax_callback.jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataSet>
        <
            exception 

                    text="Complimenti. Registrazione avvenuta con successo."        
        />
```

And this is the error of xml

```
Errore interpretazione XML: la dichiarazione XML o testuale non è all’inizio di un’entità Indirizzo: moz-nullprincipal:{d84efa50-0bb7-4f19-b93a-de7ebc15f366} Riga numero 3, colonna 1:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
^
```

I think the error is on the ajax_callback.jsp

Comment: Ok , because I think that I have get code from a hold version of jsp. But, how can I fixed it?

Comment: Ok, I know, I have that error when I try to insert the code that one user have suggest me, then he have delete your answer. Now I have replace his code with the original code, and I don't have any error, but the lenght of the element is 0 always.

and othe question, this code is deprecated?
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
The question is how can I read the model from controller to JSP?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem in this mode, (with this code)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@ page contentType="text/xml"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<dataSet>
   <c:forEach var="dataItem" items="${dataSet}">
        <<c:out value="${dataItem.tagName}"/> 
        <c:forEach var="attribute" items="${dataItem.attributes}">
            <c:out value="${attribute.id}"/>="<c:out value='${attribute.description}'/>" 
        </c:forEach>/>
    </c:forEach>
</dataSet>
```

I have moved the row of `"<?xml...."` how to first row and now works